# Change of data in the grid view based on change in a dropdown

Tags: php, yii

I have 3 tables in mysql

1. city in which I have Cityid Cityname
2. labels in which I have
       labelid langid and text
3. language table in which I have langid,
       langname and enabled

Now the 3 tables are interrelated as cityname=labelid
text will hold the actual name
language will hold the language name
eg

City Table will be        `

- cityid=1, cityname=3000
- cityid=2, cityname=3001

`

Labels Table will be

- labelid =3000, langid=1,  text=New York

  - labelid =3000, langid=23,  text=New York in Chinese
  - labelid= 3001, langid=1,  text= Mumbai

Language Table will be

- `langid=1, lagname=english, enabled=1
- langid=23, langname=chinese, enabled=1`

Now what I have achieved is to display the data of city in grid view and show a dropdown of all the languages whose `enabled=1`

What I want to do is change the content of the grid according to the language we have selected from the drop down.

So when Chinese is selected in the drop down then all the city names should appear in Chinese.

my view code is

```
$Labelcriteria = new CDbCriteria;
$Labelcriteria->condition = ("enabled=1");
$langarray= Language::model()->findAll($Labelcriteria);
$i=-1;
foreach ($langarray as $lang)
{
    $i=$i+1;
    $langName[$i]=$lang->langname;
}

//echo CHtml::dropDownList('select_box_name','select_value',$langName,array('onchange' => 'alert(1)',));


echo CHtml::link('Advanced Search','#',array('class'=>'search-button')); ?>    

<div class="search-form" style="display:none">    
    <?php    
    $this->renderPartial('_search',array('model'=>$model,));
    ?>
</div><!-- search-form -->    

<?php
echo CHtml::dropDownList('select_box_name','select_value',$langName, array(
    'onchange'=>'alert(1)',
    'ajax' => array(
        'type'=>'POST', //request type
        'url'=>CController::createUrl('cityController/dynamiccities'), 
     )
));

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView',
    array('id'=>'city-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array('citycode', 'cityname',array('class'=>'CButtonColumn',),),));
?>
```

While my model is

```
public function search()
{    
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->select = 't.citycode,lbl.text as cityname ';
    $criteria->join = 'inner join labels lbl on t.cityname=lbl.labelid inner join language lng on lbl.langid=lng.langid';
    $criteria->order = 'lbl.text ASC';
    $criteria->condition=$someway_to_change_dynamically_using_dropdown;

    $criteria->compare('citycode',$this->citycode,true);
$criteria->compare('cityname',$this->cityname,true);    

    //  $criteria->compare('cityid',$this->cityid);
    //  $criteria->compare('seq_no',$this->seq_no);
    //  $criteria->compare('enable',$this->enable);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array('criteria'=>$criteria,));
}
```

Any help will be really appreciated

This is the controller action which renders the view file

```
public function Admin()
    {
    $model=new City();
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values






    if(isset($_GET['City']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['City'];
    $this->render('admin',array('model'=>$model));


     }
```

Comment: Not sure what this is about: `$model->attributes=$_GET['City'] and Labels::model()->findAll('text');` That's a logical operator, what's the desired behaviour? Because as it stands that doesn't make alot of sense, not to me at least, I may be missing something it's early :p

Answer (score 2):

OK I've tried to wrap my head around it and I think I have it.

You want to show all the city names in English by default, but have a drop down with all the available languages in.  When the language is switched, show the city names in that language.

So what you need is to have the grid view filled with all the name pulled out using a parameter, specified by the drop down, but defaulting to English. Your most of the way there.

Your countries are pulled out here:

```
....dget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView',
    array('id'=>'city-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
....
```

I'm guessing you want to just show the code and the translated name within the grid view?

So the widget will become:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView',
    array('id'=>'city-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'citycode', 
        array(        
             'name'=>'Country',
             'value'=>'$data->getLabel("'.$langId.'")',
        ),  
        array('class'=>'CButtonColumn')
    ),
));
```

On your city model you then need a method to get its langauge variant out based on the ID of the langauge, so place this into your model:

```
public function getLabel($id){
    return $this->labels[$id]->text;
}
```

You'll also need the proper realationship for the labels for each cityname too. Because your below Yii 1.1.9 and your not pulling them down together (joining) we'll need a manual function to join a FK to a FK.

Add this to your city Model:

```
 public function getLabels(){
      return Labels::model()->findAll(array(
          'condition'=>'labelid = :labelid',
          'params'=>array(':labelid'=>$this->cityname)
      ));
 }
```

and change its search function to:

```
public function search()
{    
  $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

  $criteria->order = 'lbl.text ASC';
  $criteria->compare('citycode',$this->citycode,true);
  $criteria->compare('cityname',$this->cityname,true);  
  $criteria->compare('cityid',$this->cityid);
  $criteria->compare('seq_no',$this->seq_no);
  $criteria->compare('enable',$this->enable);

  return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array('criteria'=>$criteria,));
}
```

Now you'll need to modify the action send the right variables into the view:

```
public function Admin($lang=1)
{
    $model=new City();
    //populate the filters
    $model->attributes = $_GET['City'];
    $this->render('admin',array('model'=>$model, 'langId'=>$lang));
 }
```

Then the search form needs to show all the available countries, which you've got already pulled out here:

```
$Labelcriteria = new CDbCriteria;
$Labelcriteria->condition = ("enabled=1");
$langarray= Language::model()->findAll($Labelcriteria);
$i=-1;
foreach ($langarray as $lang)
{
    $i=$i+1;
    $langName[$i]=$lang->langname;
}
```

This could be replaced without any change to the results with:

```
 $langarray = Language::model()->findAll(array('condition'=>'enabled=1','select'=>'langname'));
```

....I think

Either way, you have the countries there and are already popluating a drop down with them.

So all that should give you a view with the drop down of langauges and a grid view with the city names populated with English names by default, but if you pass the lang parameter with an ID it will show cities with that language.

How you implement the Javascript to actually update the grid view on Ajax will on the rest of your page layout, framework and splitting out some more views. But we can get into that another time.

Comment: Thank God I had lost hope that this could be actually possible LOL. Yes it is right on target.

Comment: Good good, well if you give it a go just getting the gridview populated with the defaults and getting the drop down filled then we can go from there, because Yii provides a big help after that point.

Comment: Hey the drop down works great. Could you put a little more light on the default condition. I am a little lost. Do you want me to add it to the $criteria in the model or in the actual grid?

Comment: Can you update the question with the action that runs this view? So I can see where the `$model` is defined. It will in there that you'll change create the data provider with the right criteria, and provide the model for searching.

Comment: Hi sorry for updating so late. I have added the controller code. Hope it's what you wanted. Thanks a Ton.

Comment: Hey sorry about that. I was using it to change the grid using another method. That didnt work as the grid did change but would get reset to the defualt lang if you clicked on another page. Plus it was a very messy logic and did not use ajax.

Comment: The controller action is just the basic admin action.

Comment: OK I've updated pretty much the entire answer, give that one a go and see where you get to.

Comment: hi, hope you are fine. I did try to implement the above code but got an error `preg_split() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given` for the line `return $this->labels[$id]->text;`. No clue why am I getting the error. Thanks for your help

Comment: That error probably isn't actually caused by that line, that's just where it's reporting, can you paste the full error with stacktrace on something like pastebin.com?

Comment: (http://pastebin.com/8DRFudnz) Here is the link> I have pasted the full error here.

Comment: ah, what version of Yii are you using?

Comment: if it's before 1.1.9 you can either upgrade (recommended) or replace the relation line with this: `'labels'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'YOUR_LABELS_MODEL_NAME', '', 'on'=>'labelid = cityname'), 'index'=>'labelid')`

Comment: (http://pastebin.com/Ydn4WGA9). New error. I have just changed the function name from  Admin to Poplang. Thanxxx

Comment: Ooops, I left a close bracket in that relation I just posted, remove that.

Comment: So your relation should read: `'labels'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'YOUR_LABELS_MODEL_NAME', '', 'on'=>'labelid = cityname', 'index'=>'labelid')` ? because that error looks like it's reading the `index` part as a new relation.

Comment: ok that was the problem. Now I am really embarrassed. (http://pastebin.com/3GjH9nDL). This is the new error.

Comment: OK you probably want to go through and check the column names, model names, and variable names that I used throughout the code, a lot was assumed from your question like column names and such. That error shows a column isn't found, I assumed `labelid` was the city name that the label row referred to. Just check those otherwise I'm stabbing in the dark.

Comment: Hi, I have just added a few more table rows so that you can get a clearer idea. I think the error is due to the relation because cityname cannot be added to a relation in city model. You can just add columns of labels table . I am not sure though and I am just assuming. Thanks

Comment: OK on the end of the `labels` relation add another parameter `'together'=>true`. That should force the labels to be pulled down with the city at the same time in one query.

Comment: OK What are the primary keys on the city and labels table?

Comment: The primary key for city table is cityid, for languages table the primary key is langid and for labels it is a composite key with a combination of labelid and langid. Labels doesn't require any user interface so although crud doesnt work for composite key its not needed. Thanks

Comment: Right I've included the search function changes in my answer now too. This is good though it's getting close, it's rendering the gridview, just failing because the right data isn't coming out of the search function. So if what I posted doesn't work just have a play around with it see if you can get it just drawing the basic grid view and work from there.

Comment: The comment thread under this is getting quite long, consider using [chat]?

Comment: @Tim I tried to hit convert to a chat but Dhaval doesn't have a high enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for updating the content of a `GridView` with respect to  the selection on a `CHtml::dropDownList`.

1)The js script is for capturing the onchange of the select:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('sel_status', "
        $('#selStatus').change(function() {
            //alert(this.value);
            $.fn.yiiGridView.update('milestone-category-grid', {
                    data: $(this).serialize()
            });            
            return false;
        });
    ");
```

2)Code for the select:

```
$data = CHtml::listData(Status::model()->findAll('IsProcess=?',array(1)), 'ID', 'Description');

$select = key($data);

echo CHtml::dropDownList(
    'dropDownStatus',
    $select,            // selected item from the $data
    $data,       
    array(
        'style'=>'margin-bottom:10px;',
        'id'=>'selStatus',
    )
);
```

3)For the gridview widget:

```
 $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
        'id'=>'milestone-category-grid',
        'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'installSortable',
        'enableSorting' => false,
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search($select),
        'rowCssClassExpression'=>'"items[]_{$data->ID}"',
        'columns'=>array(
            'Description',
        ),
    )); ?>
```

4)In the `Search` function of your corresponding model the following code needs to capture the GET variable that is being passed, in this case it is `dropDownStatus`, the name given to the select (use Firebug, if necessary, to get the name of the variable being passed):

```
public function search($status=false)
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        if ($status!==false) {
            $criteria->condition='StatusID=:StatusID';
            $criteria->params=array('StatusID'=>$status);
        }

        if (isset($_GET['dropDownStatus'])) {
            $criteria->condition='StatusID=:StatusID';
            $criteria->params=array('StatusID'=>$_GET['dropDownStatus']);
            $criteria->order='Position ASC';
        }

...
```

[Reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/648/update-gridview-with-dropdown-selection/)